# PHP query returns null only (online php myadmin)

Tags: php

**i tried to run these codes manually at url but it returns null values**

> 1.when admin accept the request status will be updated as in first query
>
> 2.second query will fetched remain_leave
>
> 3.third query will update the found difference from remain_leave and
>       ldays

```
<?php
 $con=mysql_connect("","","");
$db=mysql_select_db('',$con);

$status=$_REQUEST['status'];
$eid=$_REQUEST['eid'];
$ldays=$_REQUEST['ldays'];
$leave=0;

 $result=mysql_query("update user_request set status='$status' where eid  
 ='$eid'") or die("error");

$result1=mysql_query("select remain_leave  from user where id='$id'");

while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
{
$leave=$row['remain_leave'];

}

$diff=$leave-$ldays;

$result=mysql_query("update user set remain_leave=$diff where id    
='$eid'") or die("error");


echo json_encode($respon);
?>
```

Comment: Errors... if any? Plus, `$respon` that's undefined.

Comment: Tell you what: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`, see what that says.

Answer (score 0):

```
select remain_leave  from user where id='$id'
```

$id isn't defined, so it will always be running this query

```
select remain_leave  from user where id=''
```

Also note that

`mysql_query` and related functions are deprecated and slated for removal in a later release. `mysqli` or `PDO` are recommended in its place

And that if `$id` is meant to come from the user like `$eid` then directly inserting it into the query like that is vulnerable to SQL injection.  See: [What is SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)

As mentioned by Fred -ii in the comments, `$respon` is also undefined in your final echo